# Glitch - MongoError: failed to connect to server [undefined:27017]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, glitch-framework

I am going through [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/)'s curriculum. I am still a back end newbie.

I am currently in [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/apis-and-microservices/apis-and-microservices-projects/exercise-tracker) project. In order do the project, we are supposed to "fork" it in Glitch or GitHub.

> Start this project on Glitch using [this](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/remix/clone-from-repo?REPO_URL=https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/boilerplate-project-exercisetracker/) link or clone this
>   repository on GitHub! If you use Glitch, remember to save the link to
>   your project somewhere safe!

However, as soon as I fork the project I am getting this error:

```
MongoError: failed to connect to server [undefined:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017]
```

The only thing I touched is `mongoose.connect` in order to link my database.

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MLAB_URI)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like you have not set `MLAB_URI` in your environment.

Comment: @D.SM it was set! Still not working...

Comment: What happens if you `console.log` it in the program?

Comment: `.env: line 1: dbname: No such file or directory
undefined
 Your app is listening on port 3000`

So I guess you are right. However, it appears as created in my .env file: https://imgur.com/a/HzHgOFt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... I am ashamed of answering my own question like this:

People, don't forget the quotes (or double quotes) at the beginning and end of your database URI.

Inside .env file ---> Variable Name = "Your URI"